# Complex Circuit Analysis Homework Question

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

1. Assuming the diode conducts. This is a case where you need to establish an equation using KCL. To do so, let’s assume voltage VB is an unknown. Given this, what’s VA expressed in terms of VB? What’s current i1 flowing in R1 (again, expressed in VB)? Similarly, what’s current i2, i3, and i4 (i.e. current flowing in R2, R3, and R4 respectively)?
2. Using KCL, write down an equation that relates i1, i2, i3, and i4 (you can assume these currents all flow from top to down in the circuit)?

What I tried was

VA = 1 + VB

2VB + 1 = Vcc

2VB +1 = 1000(i1), i1 = (2VB+1)/1000

VB+1 = 2000(i2), i2 = (VB+1)/20000

2VB +1 = 2000(i3), i3 = (2VB+1)/2000

VB = 1000(i4), i4 = VB/1000

and i1+2i2=2i3+i4

But solving this equation does not seem to work. I'm not an EE major so I'm doing this somewhat blindly. I'm not sure if this information is necessary, but a previous question: :If Vcc=5V, does the diode conduct? If your answer is yes, then the diode conducts, in this case, what would be the voltage difference between VA and VB?:

I'm not sure if I can assume Vcc to be equal to 5.

Comment: In terms of i1, i2, i3, and i4, only, what current flows out of Vcc plus, and what current flows into Vcc minus?

Comment: NB: Vcc is at the left.Ok. One can consider that Vcc is also at the right. So, one can apply Thevenin at the left and also apply Thevenin at the right. One can then calculate Id if diode can conduct ...

Comment: From KCL: \$I_D=\frac{V_B-V_{CC}}{R_3}+\frac{V_B}{R_4}\$ and \$I_D=\frac{V_{CC}-V_A}{R_1}-\frac{V_A}{R_2}\$. But \$V_A=V_B+1\$. So \$\frac{V_B-V_{CC}}{R_3}+\frac{V_B}{R_4}=\frac{V_{CC}-V_B-1}{R_1}-\frac{V_B+1}{R_2}\$. From that you can re-arrange to find \$V_{CC}=V_B\cdot\frac{\frac1{R_1}+\frac1{R_2}+\frac1{R_3}+\frac1{R_4}}{\frac1{R_3}+\frac1{R_4}}+\frac{\frac1{R_1}+\frac1{R_2}}{\frac1{R_3}+\frac1{R_4}}=2\cdot V_B+1\$. Right? Plug that back into \$I_D\$ to find that \$V_B\ge 1\$.

Comment: @jonk Clever, putting complete homework solutions in comments so they can't be down-voted. But why, what are you trying to prove?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Another perspective: jonk is giving autodidacts an edge.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Sorry, but I don't think it does anyone any good to hand out solutions to students. We should be giving them hints and telling them which steps they did incorrectly.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson There’ll be people who just use this aid to skip doing the work. Those will do it anyway, just asking in different places, using solution manuals, etc. But there are those who have no ill intent and genuinely want to learn and sometimes need to see a problem with a worked solution. I understand the no-straight-solutions directive, but I also think it penalizes those who aren’t out to cheat. A policy literally driven by cheaters…

Answer (score 1):

First, solve this symbolically.

Then get the formula for the diode voltage as a function of VCC. Then determine what is the VCC threshold at which your idealized diode begins to conduct.

Then formulate your answer as follows:

> For VCC below (threshold value), the circuit is described by following equations (equations follow).
>
> For VCC above (threshold value), the circuit is described by as follows (equations follow).